# Write a function that for a given a non-negative int n, returns the count of the occurrences of 9 as a digit

Tags: c, function, recursion, iteration

I can't solve this problem and I've been trying to wrap my head around it for a couple of days now. Here's the full text of the problem:

> Write a function that for a given a non-negative int `n`, returns the count of the occurrences of `9` as a digit, except that a `9` with another `9` immediately to its left counts double, so `9912349` yields 4.

The problem has two parts, a) and b).

a) part requires that this problem be solved using recursion, and

b) part requires iteration.

I'm mostly having trouble with the recursive problem. Here's my code for a) part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Write a function that for a given a non-negative int n, computes the count of the 
occurrences of 9 as a digit, except
that an 9 with another 9 immediately to its left counts double, so 9914329 yields 4. */

int recursiveNines(int mynumber) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (mynumber = 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (mynumber / 10 == 9) {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (mynumber / 10 == 9 && mynumber / 100 == 9) {
        counter += 2;
    }
    return mynumber + recursiveNines(mynumber / 10);
}
```

I think the function is okay, but I'm unsure how to return the final counter and therefore test my function.

Here's my code for the iteration of this problem:

```
int iterateNines(int mynumber) {
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        if (mynumber / 10 == 9) {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (mynumber / 10 == 9 && mynumber / 100 == 9) {
            counter+=2;
        }
    } while (mynumber != 0);

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: The `else if (mynumber / 10 == 9 && mynumber / 100 == 9)` branch will never be taken, by construction, because the first branch will be taken first. Swap the two tests. And replace your tests with `mynumber % 100 == 99` and `mynumber % 10 == 9`.

Comment: "...for a given a non-negative int n..." -- I think that's a typo, the second "a" doesn't make sense. In any case, can you give examples of input and according output? What does your function output?

Comment: Should it return `5` or `6` for `999`?

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled and pay attention to them.

Comment: Typo: replace `if (mynumber = 0)` by `if (mynumber == 0)`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you, I've changed the mynumber / 10 to mynumber % 10 and that makes more sense now, and I've also swapped the if branches. I still don't get my desired result unfortunately...

Comment: See the answers then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt here is an example: if I were to call on this function in main, for the value `996`, I get 1104.  However, I get 1104 every time, meaning that it's not an address, but instead a fixed value...

Comment: The input and expected output should be in your question, along with a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- There is a typo in `if (mynumber = 0)`: this assigns `0` to `mynumber` and evaluates to false.
- Furthermore, your test `if (mynumber / 10 == 9)` does not check if the last digit of `mynumber` is a `9`: you should instead use

  ```
  if (mynumber % 10 == 9)
  ```
- The `else` clause is incorrect too: you should instead check for a second `9` if the last digit is a `9` already. Testing this condition in the `else` branch would always fail.
- The `return` statement is incorrect: you should add `counter`, not `mynumber` to the recursive call.

Here are modified versions:

```
int recursiveNines(int mynumber) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (mynumber == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (mynumber % 10 == 9) {
        counter++;
        if (mynumber / 10 % 10 == 9)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter + recursiveNines(mynumber / 10);
}

int iterateNines(int mynumber) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (mynumber != 0) {
        if (mynumber % 10 == 9) {
            counter++;
            if (mynumber / 10 % 10 == 9) {
                counter++;
        }
        mynumber /= 10;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Here is an alternative for the recursive version using a single expression:

```
int recursiveNines(int n) {
    return (n == 0) ? 0 :
           (n % 10 == 9) + (n % 100 == 99) + recursiveNines(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation of the errors and mistakes in my original code. This has helped me immensely

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

- `mynumber = 0` instead of `mynumber == 0`
- The `else if (mynumber / 10 == 9 && mynumber / 100 == 9)` branch will never be taken, by construction, because the first branch will be taken first.
- You use the division (`/`) instead of the modulo (`%`).

Try:

```c
int recursiveNines(int mynumber) {
  int counter = 0;

  if (mynumber == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (mynumber % 100 == 99) {
    counter = 2;
  } else if (mynumber % 10 == 9) {
    counter = 1;
  }
  return counter + recursiveNines(mynumber / 10);
}
```

Comment: That second `if` really needs an `else`, otherwise counter will never be 2.

Comment: Oops, right, of course. Fixed.